# React how to change background of button with styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, background, styled-components

I implemented filter by a category to my app, so If you click on the button it filter out the specified category. I would like also change background color of the button when user clicks on it, so you can see visually which category is selected
.

I am using styled components for styling but I cannot access state in the styled component, so I dont know to what I can compare if it is clicked or not.

I tried it via props in the styled components but it did not work for me. So the question is what is the easiest way to change the background of button when the button is active.

Code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-flower-nui32?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `key` as a prop, as it is used by react internally.

You can simply set another prop and refer to that and it will work:

```js
<StyledButton
  category={category}
  buttonCategory={item} //new prop
  key={item}
  onClick={() => {
    setCategory(item);
  }}
>
```

Then just update your ternary:

```
prop.buttonCategory === prop.category ? "#23d997" : null;
```